# Changing node/%/edit title

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have created custom content type for upload the details. I have used [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to set the node title as "Upload". When I edit the node in node/%/edit the title remains "Upload". I want the title to be "Edit" .How to do this?

Comment: Could you please paste your alter code? And I didn't get where you want the "Upload" title? you want this title to be seen just in create form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'form-id') {
   if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == 'edit'){
     drupal_set_title('Upload Edit');
    }
    else{
     drupal_set_title('Upload'); }

  }
}
```

Comment: Which form ID would you check to be sure it's the node edit form being shown?

Answer (score 0):

After searching finally found the answer. Place this code in your template.php

```
if (!empty($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#form_id']) && $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#form_id'] == 'YOUR FORM ID') {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'edit') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Edit Content');
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_title("Upload Content");
  }}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
$node = node_load(your nid);
$node->title = 'new title';
node_save($node);
```